# как определить длину тормозного пути (инерции) юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Существует игра про корабль, который плывет вперед, используя rigetBody.addForce, когда импульсы останавливаются, корабль начинает останавливаться с инерцией, как я могу понять, в какой момент корабль полностью остановится (как определить тормозной путь)?

PS - корабль - это 2-й объект.

Comment: А простая физика t = V/a - не подходит? где V - скорость объекта, а - ускорение (или в данном случае торможение)

Answer (score 0):

В Unity работают большинство законов физики и здесь не исключение думаю. Формула для тормозного пути `S=V^2/2gu` , но в вашем случае источник это импульс `P = mV`, откуда `V = P/m`. Финальная формула для вас: `S=P^2 / 2*m^2*g*u`. Где `P` импульс , который вы указали в addForce, `m` - масса как компонент rigidbody, `g` - значение gravity вашего корабля как компонент rigidbody, `u` - сила трения воды(как бы странно не звучало), точнее материала для воды. Про материал можете почитать тут https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html. Для земли это сработает , но с водой я не имел проектов , возможно там также. Здесь больше вопрос к физикам). Извиняюсь за мой русский , я далеко не носитель этого языка.